# Replacing charcters being pointed by with different character

Tags: c

More specifically, I'm trying to replace a four character word being pointed by my pointer with four asterisks without using character array.
So if I had the word `char *word = "Word"` using this method would return `****`.

Here is what I have so far,

```
void four_stars(char *start){
    char *temp = start;
    int length = 0;
    while(*temp){
        length++;
        temp++;
    }
    if(length==4){
        while(length>=0){
            start = '*';
            start++;
            length--;
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it with the word `char *word = "This"` and the output was just `This` which is the same word.
I'm very new to c programming, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `while(length>=0){ start = '*';` --> `while(length>0){ *start = '*';` , at caller `char word[] = "This"`

Comment: Instead of `start = '*'; start++;` you should do `*start++ = '*'`, as well as @BLUEPIXY loop test `>0`.

Comment: Technical point: your code treats `"ab !"` as a four letter word as well.

Comment: Is there a practical reason you cannot use `strlen` to get the length?

Comment: that gives me segfault :( @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @Jongware I thought first while loop with `while(*temp)` checks for 4 characters, and it's a part of a assignment and it doesn't let me use other external things.

Comment: @Leon `char *word = "This"` replace with `char word[] = "This"`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I can't use character arrays

Comment: @Leon Can not change the string literal. it's UB. It is the cause of the seg-fault.

Comment: `char *word = malloc(5); strcpy(word, "This");` LOL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `char *word = "Word"` then it is not possible to modify `"Word"`. This is because, in C and C++, string literals are not modifiable. You have to start with a string which is in a writable memory area, e.g.:

```
char word[] = "Word";
```

or

```
char *word = malloc(5);
strcpy(word, "Word");
```

Then your function would work (if you change `start = '*';` to `*start = '*';`).

Comment: But I can change individual characters being pointed to by a pointer right?

Comment: @Leon Yes, so long as those characters are modifiable.  You cannot change non-modifiable things.

Answer (score -1):

```
// the code you wrote has a few flaws
// rather than trying to list the flaws
// I just provide a simplistic/brute force example to accomplish the function

void four_stars(char *start)
{
    start[0] = '*';
    start[1] = '*';
    start[2] = '*';
    start[3] = '*';
}
```

Comment: That ignores the required length of 4 for `start`.

Comment: ^
I only want to replace the word if it has a length of 4 and only 4.